# printer.printFile prints empty string

Tags: typescript

I am using the compiler API to create Typescript code. After assigning `const printer = createPrinter()`, I can use `printer.printNode` and `printer.printList` to print my AST. But for some reason, `printer.printFile` always prints empty strings.

```js
const printer = createPrinter();
    
const sourceFile = createSourceFile(
  'dummy.ts',
  '',
  ScriptTarget.ESNext,
  false,
  ScriptKind.TS
);

const classDeclaration = factory.createClassDeclaration(
  undefined,
  undefined,
  'Foo',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  []
);

factory.updateSourceFile(sourceFile, factory.createNodeArray([classDeclaration]));

console.log(printer.printFile(sourceFile)); // '';
```

Why is `printer.printFile` always printing an empty string?

Comment: Came across the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but it looks like the `factory.updateSourceFile` returns the updated `SourceFile`.

```js
const printer = createPrinter();
   
// const -> let 
let sourceFile = createSourceFile(
  'dummy.ts',
  '',
  ScriptTarget.ESNext,
  false,
  ScriptKind.TS
);

const classDeclaration = factory.createClassDeclaration(
  undefined,
  undefined,
  'Foo',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  []
);

// assign the updated source file
sourceFile = factory.updateSourceFile(sourceFile, factory.createNodeArray([classDeclaration]));

console.log(printer.printFile(sourceFile));
// class Foo {
// }
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel a bit dumb now. I get that they don't want to mutate the source file in a function, but still, updateSourceFile is a pretty strange name choice.